# Torch on Gentoo

Tags: torch

Has anyone tried to install Torch on top of Gentoo Linux Distribution?

I'm very familiar with this distribution, but I'm totally new at torch. Googling a little, I found that Gentoo is not officially supported by torch (take a look at the install-deps script, line 142: https://github.com/torch/distro/blob/master/install-deps), but some users have successfully installed it, even if the corresponding tutorial is a little bit aged (http://spotofdata.com/installing-torch-gentoo/).

I'm wondering if someone has tried the tandem gentoo/torch and, in that case, if her/he would suggest it in spite of the more traditional ones (arch/torch or ubuntu/torch) and if there are some issues/recommendations in using it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wanted to do the same thing, like yesterday, which is how I came across your post. You might also try [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/torch7/mtNfCLlQNSU) that has a modified installation script for gentoo. I haven't gotten very far and know almost nothing about lua, but I have verified that after running the installation script I can load and run some basic torch scripts.

[edit: fixed typo]